# HSPICE - Measuring a series of values in transient simulation

Tags: spice

I'm doing a transient simulation in HSPICE with an input vector file of N values (N>100).

I would like to get at each rising edge of the clock (i.e. timing of the shape kT, T period, k integer)  a measure of a value of the current. My goal is then to process those values through a script.

Does anyone know how to do that please?
I can't use N times the .MEAS statements as N is really huge...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hspice .MEASURE Continuous Results

This is from the 2014.09 Hspice command reference:

```
.MEASURE (Continuous Results)
Measures continuous results for TRIG-TARG, FIND-WHEN, Equation, and PARAM Evaluation functions.
Syntax
...
```

Examples from the documentation:

```
Example 2 The .measure statement continuously reports the time when the voltage value of node a1 reaches 2.5V, starting from the second falling edge.
.measure tran_cont cont_vout1 when v(a1)=2.5 fall=2

Example 3 The following example shows a correct .measure statement.
.measure tran_cont PERIOD
+ TRIG v(out) VAL =VDD/2 RISE=1
+ TARG v(out) VAL =VDD/2 RISE=2
.measure tran_cont FREQUENCY PARAM=1/PERIOD
```

The output will be in a separate continuous measures file

### Hspice .MEASURE generation

Make a perl/python/whatever script that generates a .measure for each edge. Include the .measure statements into your hspice deck. The ostensible advantage of this is that the results will reside with the rest of the measurements.

### VerilogA block

One can write a VerilogA piece of code which can be triggered by edges to output the time into a file. In Cadence there should be a sample library with some sample VerilogA widgets. The VerilogA code should be included into the hspice deck with a .hdl command and should be instantiated like any other subcircuit. Possible VerilogA code (in this case connect the signal of interest to the 'in' of this sampler:

```
`include "disciplines.vams"

module sampler(in);
input in; electrical in;

parameter real thres=0.5;

integer fh;

analog begin
  @(initial_step) begin
    fh = $fopen("times.txt","w");
  end
  @(final_step) begin
    $fclose(fh);
  end
  @(cross(V(in)-thres, +1, 10p)) begin
  //                   +1 means rising edge only
    $fstrobe(fh,"%g",$abstime);
  end
end
endmodule
```

### PyOPUS post-processing

If you're looking for a more general post-procesing Python environment use [PyOPUS](http://fides.fe.uni-lj.si/pyopus/).  [PyOPUS](http://fides.fe.uni-lj.si/pyopus/) will open Hspice POST_VERSION=9601 binary data into numpy data structures. A post-processing script might look like:

```py
import pyopus.simulator.hspicefile as hspf
import pyopus.evaluator.measure as meas

hspfObj = hspf.hspice_read( 'netlist.tr0' )
if hspfObj is None:
    raise Exception("Error opening hspice file")

results = hspfObj[0][0][2][0]  # dictionary of waveforms, keyed by name
time = results[hspfObj[0][1]]  # list of scale point (in this case time)

i_rises = meas.IatXval(results['out'], 0.5, slope='rising')
t_rises = meas.XatI(time, i_rises)
```